# React - Using render props with conditional components causes hooks error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Given this minimal example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Component({ num }) {
    const [lorem, setLorem] = useState('lorem');
    return (
        <div>
            {num}: {lorem}
        </div>
    );
}

function AnotherComponent({ render = Component }) {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
                Open
            </button>
            {isOpen ? render({ num: 123 }) : null}
        </div>
    );
}
```

When running a unit test that clicks the button I get the error `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`.

The error kind of makes sense - on one render the `useState('lorem')` isn't in the document, then when the button is clicked, it is. However, this error does not occur when I define the Component using JSX (i.e. `{isOpen ? <Component num={123} /> : null}` but it does when I try to use the render prop.

Is there a way to use the render prop pattern like this and avoid the hooks error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, you need to use `render` as a JSX tag, otherwise the hook calls within `render` aren't considered as part of a separate component, but rather as part of `AnotherComponent`. In React, JSX tags that aren't inbuilt must start with a capitalized letter, so you can alias the destructured `render` prop to be `Render`, and then use it as a component:

```js
function AnotherComponent({ render: Render = Component }) { // alias the render prop
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
                Open
            </button>
            {isOpen ? <Render num={123} /> : null}
        </div>
    );
}
```